# JSON PARSE retornando 'object object'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Gostaria de saber o que está errado com a minha função, pois ao atribuir `obj = data`, o mesmo salva `object object`, sendo que o valor de data é um JSON retornado pelo WEBSERVICE.

Valor de data:

```
[{"descricao":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tristique \nligula sed nibh finibus, id placerat elit mollis. Proin dictum sed felis vitae vulputate. Nunc vitae velit feugiat, porttitor \nfelis quis, pharetra risus. Integer id dolor sapien. Aenean ultricies, risus at lacinia blandit, leo mi tincidunt risus, \nat gravida nisi nisl ut dui. Donec vitae consectetur urna. Phasellus at augue vel nisl semper aliquet eu vel ante. Ut venenatis \nlacus id velit aliquet, ac congue neque mollis. Quisque at elit mollis arcu condimentum imperdiet.","idEvento":3,"inicio":"05/10","palestrante":"Profº José Marinho","qtdVagas":40,"termino":"09/10","titulo":"Palestra de Jogos"}]
```

Função JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnSubmit").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/SemanaEngenharia/webresources/services.evento",
            data: "", /* redundante */
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                obj = JSON.parse(data); /* nao funciona*/
                //$("#p").html(obj.titulo);
                alert(obj);
            }

        }); // fim ajax

    });
});
```

Ao fazer `obj.titulo` (um dos campos do JSON), o retorno é "undefined".

Comment: Já tentou definir o `dataType` como JSON para não precisar fazer a conversão manualmente?

Comment: Se há os colchetes é porque está convertendo um *array* de objetos. Se não precisa do *array*, converta direto o objeto. Sem ver o código por traz de tudo isso é impossível dizer.

Comment: Encontrei o erro. No meu webservice, ele retorna uma lista com todos os eventos, por isso os colchetes. Como eu poderia mudar isso? estou usando JPA

Comment: Pesquise na documentação o que o [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) faz que entenderá.

Comment: meu metodo no java: https://imgur.com/a/7MYuQcT

ele retorna uma lista, por isso os colchetes e por isso não está funcionando o parse json. Teria alguma possibilidade de alterar a estrutura desse JPA sem usar lista?

Comment: Para o caso de alterar o Java para que ele retorne uma estrutura diferente, eu sugiro que [faça outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) especificamente sobre isso (só não esqueça de fazer uma busca antes para ver se esta pergunta já existe no site).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `alert` não mostra o conteúdo do objeto. Se você fizer um `console.log` irá mostrar. Como é um objeto array, você acessa os valores pelo índice 0, já que é um array de apenas um item JSON, por exemplo:

```
obj[0].descricao;
```

Irá acessar o valor da chave `descricao`.

Agora você pode trocar o `dataType` por `json` para que a string já venha parseada, sem a necessidade de usar `JSON.parse`:

```
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "conecta2.php",
     data: "", /* redundante */
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
         alert(data);
         //$("#p").html(obj.titulo);
         console.log(data[0].descricao);
     }

   }); // fim ajax
```

Answer (score 3):

Seu [JSON](https://www.json.org/) é um array (pois está delimitado por `[ ]`), e dentro deste array há um *object* (delimitado por `{ }`), que é quem possui a chave "titulo".

Então basta pegar o primeiro elemento do array, e em seguida pegar o "titulo":

```js
let json = [{"descricao":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tristique \nligula sed nibh finibus, id placerat elit mollis. Proin dictum sed felis vitae vulputate. Nunc vitae velit feugiat, porttitor \nfelis quis, pharetra risus. Integer id dolor sapien. Aenean ultricies, risus at lacinia blandit, leo mi tincidunt risus, \nat gravida nisi nisl ut dui. Donec vitae consectetur urna. Phasellus at augue vel nisl semper aliquet eu vel ante. Ut venenatis \nlacus id velit aliquet, ac congue neque mollis. Quisque at elit mollis arcu condimentum imperdiet.","idEvento":3,"inicio":"05/10","palestrante":"Profº José Marinho","qtdVagas":40,"termino":"09/10","titulo":"Palestra de Jogos"}]

console.log(json[0].titulo); // Paletras de Jogos
```

Comment: Esse grupo salva minha faculdade de uma maneira surpreendente. MUITO obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: @WeslleyFillipe Não esqueça de escolher uma das respostas (caso ela tenha resolvido o seu problema) e aceitá-la (veja [no **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como fazê-lo). Não é obrigação, claro, mas é considerado boa prática do site para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. No caso, só uma das respostas pode ser aceita, então caso vc decida aceitar uma delas, escolha a que melhor resolveu o problema.

Comment: prontinho! Obrigado mais uma vez!